# Modeling a smooth curve in hard surface object

Tags: modeling, workflow

How would I go about changing the first object shape in to the second? At the moment I just seem to be going around in circles with subdivide and smooth but not actually achieving the desired result.

This is Blender 2.76 on Windows

[image: reference image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an 'L' shape, I would remove the top and bottom faces, use [bevel](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/bevel.html) <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to get the two round corners, use the <kbd>[image: MW] Wheel</kbd> to add some segments, you only want a couple of segments on the curves or you'll have too much work filling in the top.

[image: add rounded edges]

Then fill the top with an n-gon face <kbd>F</kbd> and use [inset](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/inset.html) <kbd>I</kbd> to get a clean edge loop around the top.

[image: top with an inset]

Then extend the edges from the curves to the outside to get an all quad mesh. Some more loop cuts can be made through the larger sections to get a more consistent face sizing over the mesh.

[image: extend curve edges]

Now a subsurf modifier can be added to get a more rounded finish. If you want the outer corners to stay sharp you can add a [crease](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#crease-subsurf) to them <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> and add an edge split modifier.

[image: model with modifiers]

Here is an example to look at [image]